Saving PDF in C# System.Drawing.Printing
I created a C# application to edit a page and print it, also save it as a pdf. I m facing issue in displaying image on a page. Following is the screenshot of controls of my application:
Application
Following is my code:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PDFCreator
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void preview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            printPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument;
            printPreviewDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperA4", 840, 1180);
            printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void AddLogo(PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add Logo
            Point ulCorner = new Point(60, 75);
            var img = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\temp\\PDFCreator\\Resources\\SampleLogo.png");
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, ulCorner);

        }

        private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add logo
            AddLogo(e);
        }

        private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}


Following is the sample image I m trying to display:
Sample Logo
Issue I m facing:
I m loading the image on on the page without cropping/resizing as shown in code. When I m clicking on Print Preview button I m getting correct page preview as shown below:
Print preview
There is a PrintDocument control I m using to save the document as a pdf alternatively the print preview also provides an option to save the document as pdf.
But after I m saving it as pdf I m seeing cropped image, as shown below:
Saved pdf
What can be the issue and resolution?
I have tried image after resizing it, I have also tried different image but the behavior is same.

You don't mention how you save as PDF. Some printing to a PDF PrinterDriver or a specific PDF product with different code then shown here or what?

Thank you @Ralf, I have added the required information.

Not really helpful PrintDocument does not know anything about PDF. I assume you do PrintToPDF and use a specific printer driver that does that "saving as PDF". What driver you use for that? Someone then might have ideas about the diff of the preview and actual printing of that driver as its a feature of that driver.

I would assume it is not enough to draw the image using your selected overload of e.Graphics.DrawImage, but you rather have to calculate the bounds of the image so that it fits inside of e.MarginBounds and can be scaled. DrawImage has several more overloads that don't only take a Point but also a Rectangle.

@Ralf I have made changes in settings: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers, here I have selected Microsoft Print to PDF option as default. Due to this the document will be saved as pdf when print function is called.

@LWChris I have used other overloads also like drawing image in a rectangle but the result is same The space is enough in the page to draw the image. The image size is 632x293 (width x height) and the page size is 840x1180.

@KJ I could understand little from your statement. I went in Settings->Display and found 4 options in Scale options: 100%, 125%, 150% and 175%. The default was 125% I changed it to 100% and the result was same.

Thanks @KJ, I was able to resolve the issue, I checked the DPI of the existing image, it was 120, I updated it to 72 and then saw the print preview, it was showing the cropped image in preview itself, which earlier was showing a whole image. After that I used a rectangle to draw the image inside it e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(60, 75, img.Width/2, img.Height/2));. And it is working as expected. No cropping of any type in preview as well as saved pdf file.
